# A recurrence sequence I can't solve (A level) - Any hint is appreciated.

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence is defined by 
$$\begin{aligned} u_1 &= 3 \\
u_{n+1} &= 2 — 4/u_n
\end{aligned}$$

Find the exact values of

(a) $u_2, u_3 \;\text{and}\; u_4$

(b) $u_{61}$

(c) $\sum_{i=1}^{99} u_i$

How to solve (b) and (c) without solving the preceding terms leading up to $u_{60}$ individually ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you done a)?

Comment: Yes I have, this is the first time I have encountered this type of question, (a) I am familiar with. Feeling really dumb.

Comment: No need to feel dumb, you have to struggle with one problem of that kind and afterwards you’ll master all others! As the answer said, look for patterns. If you do not see it yet, try computing $u_5$, $u_6$, $u_7$, and so on, till you get it (and you will!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part (b) you need to look for patterns.
$$u_1=3$$
$$u_2=\frac{2}{3}$$
$$u_3=-4$$
$$u_4=3$$
$$u_5=\frac{2}{3}$$
$$u_6=-4$$
(and so on)

Do you remember how to find $i^{87}$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$?  Same deal.

For part (c) you will need the identity $\sum_{k=1}^nc=cn$.